# Editing image field using Django forms

Tags: python, html, django, django-forms, django-views

I am currently creating an application that allows users to view and edit their own personal profile. I've recently added in the ability for a user to add a profile picture to their profile. I can add a profile in the admin page and it will show up on the selected users profile no problem. The problem is when the user tries to update their picture I am getting an `ValueError` telling me that the `image` attribute has no file associated. Below is how I have tried to implement the functionality.

**Models**

```
class UserProfileModel(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    age = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=254, null=True, blank=True, unique=True)
    height = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    weight = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    bio = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, default='')
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_image', blank=True)
```

**forms**

```
class UpdateProfile(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = UserProfileModel
        fields = ('email', 'age', 'height', 'weight', 'bio', 'image')
```

**views**

```
def update_profile(request):
    args = {}

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UpdateProfile(request.POST, instance=request.user.userprofilemodel)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('account:profile'))
            # return render(request, 'account/profile.html')
    else:
        form = UpdateProfile()
        if request.user.is_authenticated():
            form = UpdateProfile(instance=request.user.userprofilemodel)
        args['form'] = form
        return render(request, 'account/edit_profile.html', args)
```

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

{#<h2 style="text-align:center">User Profile Card</h2>#}

<div class="container">
  <h1>{{ user }}s Profile </h1>
  <div style="margin: 24px 0;">
        <p>Username: {{ user }}</p>
        <p>Email: {{ user.userprofilemodel.email }}</p>
        <p>Age: {{ user.userprofilemodel.age }}</p>
        <p>Height: {{ user.userprofilemodel.height }} CM </p>
        <p>Weight: {{ user.userprofilemodel.weight }} KG </p>
        <p>User Bio: {{ user.userprofilemodel.bio }} </p>
        <img src="{{ user.userprofilemodel.image.url }}" width="240">


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you may have forgotten to pass `request.FILES` to your form?

```
form = UpdateProfile(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=request.user.userprofilemodel)
```

Also, you haven't shown the template containing the form used to upload an image, but ensure that the form's `enctype` is set to `multipart/form-data`.

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```